# JBOD and DUAL mode difference

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-raid, enclosures

My dual bay HDD enclosure got JBOD and DUAL modes among other modes. What is the difference between those 2 modes? I just want to know exactly because I am connectin a single hdd with data and I don't want it to be corrupted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For standard definitions of the terms (some manufacturers are terrible about this):

JBOD = Concatenation (Data written beyond the end of the first drive is written to the second drive). Addressed as one drive by the OS.
Dual = Two independently addressable drives.